# single Template.yml mutiple lambda functions and code-build to deploy other accounts

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-sam-cli

We have the pipeline code. where it does code-commit. code-build and create and deploy changeset where it deploys to other AWS accounts. this codebase has a lambda function in the template.yaml along with java codebase. during the build phase, it creates 3 jar files. how to pack these files to create template-yml code-base. it works fine in a single lamdba function template.yml the challange is here we have lambda functions inside the template.yml

- aws cloudformation package --template-file template.yml --s3-bucket $S3Bucket --s3-prefix packages-$EnvironmentName --output-template-file template-export.yml

how to add the CodeUri: this should be like s3://bucketname/packages-/pack1/

```html
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: Outputs the time

Resources:
 
  TimeFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Handler: firstsample/firstsample.handler   # firstsample.js file is in firstsample direcotory
      Role: !GetAtt BasicAWSLambdaRole.Arn
      Runtime: java11
      CodeUri: s3://test/packages/jar1/                   
  
  SecondSampleFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Handler: secondsample.handler                  # didn't have to include secondsample directory
      Role: !GetAtt BasicAWSLambdaRole.Arn
      Runtime: java11
      CodeUri: s3://test/packages/jar2/
```

Comment: What is the problem? Can you clarify again?

Comment: Can we deploy the mutiple jars generated in the code-pipline build to the 3 different lambdas defined in the template.yml. i am able to achive using the singe jar but not mutiple jars.